# URL not dynamic when Tab is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: for reference]

I have two tabs in my shared component like in the picture below:
On page load, if the URL is /London-city/123/456/south
, when I click on the tabs the URL changes but the remaining part in the URL
disappeared as these URL's are hardcoded

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

    const London = 'London' ; 
    const Paris = 'Paris' ; 
    
    const INPUT_TYPES = [ { text : 'London' , id : 'London' , active : true }, { text : 'Paris' , id : 'Paris' }, ];
```

hardcoded like this

```
    const PATH_BY_CITY_FUNCTION = {
     London : '/London-city/' ,
     Paris : '/Paris-city/' , 
     };
```

this is tab change handler
```
const handelCityTabChange = ( id ) => {
if ( disableRouteChange ) {
setCurrentTab ( id );
return ;
}

```
    if ( PATH_BY_CITY_FUNCTION [ id ] && currentTab !== id ){
       Router . pushRoute ( PATH_BY_CITY_FUNCTION [ id ]);
    } 
 };
```

````
 const onCityTabChange = 
useCallback ( handelCityTabChange , [ currentTab , disableRouteChange ]);
 ```
this is Tab tag for tab change
````

```
  < Tab
     items = { tabInput }
     onTabChange = { ( id ) => { 
     onCityTabChange ( id );
  } } 
  >
```

Instead of these hard-coded url's I have to display the current URL when clicked on the tabs, like it should be /Paris-city/123/456/south when I click on Paris Tab and vice versa.
The latter part in the past url should get appended to the new url.

Any idea how can I achieve this.

Comment: Can you please put a little more effort into formatting your code?

Comment: Can you also specify what routing package you are using?